# Date-Picker and Time-Picker Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In PHP I have a two textbox, one for date-picker and second for time-picker.

In this, If I select today's date at 2 PM then in 2nd timepicker textbox disable time before 2PM in PHP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show what you've tried...

Comment: Why would you want to do that in PHP? Best would be to use JS (as your tag already lists it) on the client-side, have a script check the value of the date picker and disable the options after the current time in the time picker on date change.

Comment: not idea about script for date and time selection. give me a hint

Comment: Show us code!… :)

Answer (score 0):

For Time picker ::

```
$('#startTime').timepicker({
        'minTime': '6:00am',
        'maxTime': '11:30pm',
        'onSelect': function () {
            $('#endTime').timepicker('option', 'minTime', $(this).val());
        }
    });
```

For Date Picker :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dt1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
            $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
            $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        }
    });
    $('#dt2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onClose: function () {
            var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
            //check to prevent a user from entering a date below date of dt1
            if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: show example that will make us understand ur problem